# How to make page always go to top when loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to make my current web page always refresh to the top of the page.

Currently it refreshes to the bottom.

What code might I use and where would I place it?

Comment: `document.body.scrollTop = 0`

Comment: should i make that an answer? this isnt really a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Ditto, @SpYk3HH. He will also need to do it in the correct event handler (most likely onload?) so that it overrides the browser. Might create a jump.

Answer (score 2):

Here 's how you can do it with jquery:

```
  $(function() {
     $('body').scrollTop(0);
   });
```

or with javascript:

```
 document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: I plussed u any way, cause this question will likly be closed, but why `Top = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0`? why not just the short version, likes i have?

Comment: You are correct your answer is better ... I knew the jquery way and just searched for javascript but your's is cleaner

Comment: lol, i wasn't worried about who's answer was better, I had just never seen scrolltop for body assigned like that before and was curious as to why it might would work that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can set scroll head to the desired level by assigning the element head to the scrollTop on load.

eg:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".first-section").offset().top}, 2000);
});
```

So you can use the first div's id or class to scroll it up on top every time you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as inserting `document.body.scrollTop = 0` as the first line of you document load function.

```
$(function() {  //  same as $(document).ready(function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // |OR| $('body').scrollTop(0);
    /* do work */
})
```